# Error 404 Not found when upgrade Ubuntu 16.04.x to 18.04.x on a my local repo using apt-mirror

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, upgrade, update-manager, apt-mirror

I have issue when upgrading using the step `do-release-upgrade`, some links  result in "404 Not found".

This issue is shown in this screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of do-release-upgrade output]

How can I resolve  it, as I am concerned that it will affect the system?

**Host local repo Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS**

> /etc/apt/mirror.list:

```
root@local-repos-ubuntu:/var/www/html# cat /etc/apt/mirror.list
############# config ##################
#
# set base_path    /var/spool/apt-mirror
set base_path     /opt/apt-mirror
#
# set mirror_path  $base_path/mirror
# set skel_path    $base_path/skel
# set var_path     $base_path/var
# set cleanscript $var_path/clean.sh
# set defaultarch  <running host architecture>
# set postmirror_script $var_path/postmirror.sh
# set run_postmirror 0
set nthreads     20
set _tilde 0
#
############# end config ##############

##################################
##
##  UBUNTU 16.04 LTS (xenial)
##
##################################

deb https://mirror.kku.ac.th/ubuntu xenial main restricted universe multiverse
deb https://mirror.kku.ac.th/ubuntu xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb https://mirror.kku.ac.th/ubuntu xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb https://mirror.kku.ac.th/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb https://mirror.kku.ac.th/ubuntu xenial-proposed main restricted universe multiverse

##################################
##
##  UBUNTU 18.04 LTS (bionic)
##
##################################
deb https://mirror.kku.ac.th/ubuntu bionic main  restricted universe multiverse
deb https://mirror.kku.ac.th/ubuntu bionic-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb https://mirror.kku.ac.th/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb https://mirror.kku.ac.th/ubuntu bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb https://mirror.kku.ac.th/ubuntu bionic-proposed main restricted universe multiverse

##################################
##
##  GLOBAL / CLEANUP
##
##################################

clean https://mirror.kku.ac.th/ubuntu
```

**Client:**

> /etc/apt/sources.list

```
root@ubuntu-16-04:~# cat /etc/apt/sources.list
############  UBUNTU 16.04 LTS (xenial)
deb [arch=amd64] http://192.168.1.128/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted universe multiverse
deb [arch=amd64] http://192.168.1.128/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb [arch=amd64] http://192.168.1.128/ubuntu/ xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb [arch=amd64] http://192.168.1.128/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb [arch=amd64] http://192.168.1.128/ubuntu/ xenial-proposed main restricted universe multiverse
root@ubuntu-16-04:~#
```

**========== Update 2021-10-12 ==========**
This is screen short before upgrade with using command `apt  update`:
[image: This is screen short before upgrade]

This is screen short after has finished upgrade major version  xenial to bionic:
[image: Screenshot of Done upgrade 16.04 to 18.04 output] 
**Is  it ok to ignore the issue above?**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbW5D.jpg)

Comment: Correct as 16.04 is no longer supported then the links to upgrade it wont be there.

Comment: Make an 18.04 or better still a 20.04 live USB or DVD and run it from there. Choose the replace existing Ubuntu as the install option. Of course back up ALL data files you want to keep before doing the install.

Comment: Thanks you@David